# Error en los movimientos

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista

Estoy iniciando con python y tengo como trabajo hacer un sokoban muy sencillo, mi personaje ya se mueve arriba, abajo, izquierda y derecha sin embargo al moverme a la derecha de la posicion original, solo me permite moverme una sola casilla y despues me marca un error. Ademas que mi personaje no deberia pasar las paredes cosa que no se esta aplicando. Lo intente primero en un arreglo unidimensional y funciona correctamente pero al intentarlo presenta esos fallos.
File "sokoban.py", line 29, in 
    if move=='d' and mapa[position_row+1]!=2:
IndexError: list index out of range

```
    '''
0- Personaje
1- Cajas
2- Paredes
3- Metas
4- Pasillo
5- Cajas/meta

'''
mapa=  [[2,2,2,2,2,2,2],
        [2,4,4,0,4,4,2],
        [2,4,4,4,4,4,2],
        [2,4,4,4,4,4,2],
        [2,2,2,2,2,2,2]]

position_row=3
position_colum=1

while True:

    tem_row=position_row
    tem_colum=position_colum

    for i in range(len(mapa)):
        for j in range(len(mapa[i])):
            print(mapa[i][j], end=' ')
        print()

    move=input("a - left, d - right, s - down, w - up: ")
    if move=='d' and mapa[position_row+1]!=2:
        position_row=position_row+1
    elif move=='a' and mapa[position_row-1]!=2:
        position_row=position_row-1
    elif move=='w' and mapa[position_colum-1]!=2:
        position_colum=position_colum-1
    elif move=='s' and mapa[position_colum+1]!=2:
        position_colum=position_colum+1

    mapa[position_colum][position_row]=0
    mapa[tem_colum][tem_row]=4
```

Answer (score 2):

Unas cuantas observaciones:

- No defines correctamente la posición inicial del jugador, tienes `position_row=3` y `position_colum=1`, cuando es al contrario `position_row=1`
  y `position_colum=3`.
- `a` y `d` deben modificar `position_column`,  `s` y `w` `position_row`.
- Al compararar en los condicionales debes indizar usando tanto la fila como la columna para acceder al elemento. Al hacer `mapa[<int>] != 2`  simplemente accedes a una de las sublistas, a una fila, por lo que la comparación siempre será `[...] != 2`, lo cual siempre es falso (una lista siempre es diferente a un entero, son objetos distintos). Esto causa que puedas "atravesar las paredes" y terminar con un índice inválido.
- Esto no es un error como tal, pero cuando solo quieras recorrer una lista o cualquier iterable sin modificar sus items, usa un `for in` y no `for` + `range` + indizado. Es más legible, sencillo y eficiente.

Tu código podría quedar así:

```
'''
0- Personaje
1- Cajas
2- Paredes
3- Metas
4- Pasillo
5- Cajas/meta

'''
mapa = [[2,2,2,2,2,2,2],
        [2,4,4,0,4,4,2],
        [2,4,4,4,4,4,2],
        [2,4,4,4,4,4,2],
        [2,2,2,2,2,2,2]]

position_row = 1
position_colum = 3

while True:

    tem_row = position_row
    tem_colum = position_colum

    for row in mapa:
        for item in row:
            print(item, end=' ')
        print()

    move = input("a - left, d - right, s - down, w - up: ")

    if move == 'd' and mapa[position_row][position_colum + 1] != 2:
        position_colum += 1
    elif move == 'a' and mapa[position_row][position_colum - 1] != 2:
        position_colum -= 1
    elif move == 'w' and mapa[position_row - 1][position_colum] != 2:
        position_row -= 1
    elif move == 's' and mapa[position_row + 1][position_colum] != 2:
        position_row += 1
    else:
        continue

    mapa[position_row][position_colum] = 0
    mapa[tem_row][tem_colum] = 4
```